# Select distinct domains without subdomains in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table storing the referrer of users coming to my website.
I want to list all domains the users come from without subdomains.

I started using SUBSTRING_INDEX to search for the ‘.’
Challenge remains for domains like domain.co.uk where it would deliver ‘co.uk’ instead of ‘domain.co.uk’

Any ideas or best practices? :)
Thanks
Tobi

Comment: This is not easy without a function that knows the conventions for every TLD.

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of domain levels depends on the postfix then you must create additional table which stores the postfixes and according domain levels. For example, `('%.com', -2), ('%.co.uk', -3)`. And use it in your query similar to

```sql
SELECT addresses.address,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(addresses.address, 
                       '.', 
                       COALESCE(postfixes.levels, -2)
                       ) as domain
FROM addresses
LEFT JOIN postfixes ON addresses.address LIKE postfixes.postfix
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eejd5jck)

`-2` in COALESCE() is default levels amount (applied to the domains which are not present in `postfixes` table).